# separate list of programs in html/javascript coming from php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a html/php code as shown below which displays list of links coming from wordpress.

**html/php:**

```
<header class="entry-header container grid-flex">
    <div class="flex-item -sm-50">
        <button>Thumbs</button>
    </div>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($all_list); echo "</pre>";   // Line A
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "Active List<br>";
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($active_list); echo "</pre>";   // Line B
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "Passive List<br>";
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($passive_list); echo "</pre>";   // Line C
    // Load the thumbnails view
    get_template_part( 'parts/content-list-thumbs' );     // Line D
    ?>
</div>
```

**Line A** displays following list of links:

```
https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/abcdef/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/pdsfhdf

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/sdfhsw/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/dhdhdw/
```

**Line B** displays following links:

```
https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/abcdef/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/pdsfhdf
```

**Line C** displays following links:

```
https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/sdfhsw/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/dhdhdw/
```

The code inside **content-list-thumbs** file coming from **Line D** is:

**html/js code:**

```
<ul id="list-thumbs">
    <?php
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="list-grid__thumb list-grid__item">
            <a class="list-grid__img-link" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_the_permalink()); ?>">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <?php
                    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
                    CPAC\Images\the_img_fit_figure($image_id, 'list-grid__image', '(min-width: 650px) 50vw, 100vw', false); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

The above **html/js** code displays list of images associated with Line A.

**Problem Statement:**

What I want to achieve from the **html/js** code above is I want to display list of images associated with **Line B** and **Line C** with a separator.

Line B images

---

Line C images

Comment: There is no information about the "enabled" property. Where is it stored? How do you get it?

Comment: @fuxia I will check the code how I have created that Yes/No button.

Comment: @fuxia i have updated my question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: My questions remain: where is this information stored (in the database!)? How do you get it from there?

Comment: @fuxia Ok, I will check the wordpress database.

Comment: I check the wordpress database and there is no such information present for yes/no switch. Is there any way my php code can communicate with wordpress template ? or information need to be stored in wordpress database to make a communication with php code ?

Comment: @fuxia are you around ?